# How to find the orthogonal projection of a matrix onto a subspace?

Tags: projection, orthogonal-matrices, projection-matrices

$
\newcommand{\<}{\left \langle}
\newcommand{\>}{\right \rangle}
$

I have fought 2 vectors(?!) in basis which are

$M_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0\\
    0 & -1\\
    \end{bmatrix}$ and
$M_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    1 & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix}$

However, I do not know how to do the orthogonal projection of a matrix onto the subspace. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem number 2?

Consider the inner product space $\mathit M_{22}$ with the standard inner product
$\<A,B\> = tr(AB^T)$

(1) Find an orthogonal basis for the subspace $\mathit W = \{A \in M_{22}|A^T = A$ and $\mathit trA=0\}$
and explain the reason.

(2) For $\mathit A = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    1 & 1\\
    \end{bmatrix} in \space M_{22}$, find $\mathit B \in W$ such that $\|\mathit A - B\|$ ≤ $\|\mathit A - C\|$ for any $\mathit C \in W$.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have an orthogonal basis $\{M_1, M_2\}$ for $W$, the orthogonal projection of $A$ onto the subspace $W$ is simply
$$B= \left\langle A,\frac{M_1}{\|M_1\|}\right\rangle \frac{M_1}{\|M_1\|} + \left\langle A,\frac{M_2}{\|M_2\|}\right\rangle \frac{M_2}{\|M_2\|}.$$

Do you know how to prove that this orthogonal projection indeed minimizes the distance from $A$ to $W$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! I did not learn about matrix’s norm so I did some search and it has 4 kind of norms. Can you tell me which norm i need to use in this case? Frobenius?

Comment: @Ksdes219 Yes, it is the norm induced by the inner product so $\|M\| = \sqrt{\langle M,M\rangle}$.

Comment: In fact, there are many more matrix norms than four: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm.